# How can I show an input when a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I'm using React an got a problem.

The problem is to show an `<input type="text">` under a checkbox if this checkbox `isChecked`. I tried

```
option.checked ? <input type="text" id={`input_${'option.name'}` name={`name_${'option.name'}`> : null
```

but it doesn't work.

I got an example of my code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/eager-jepsen-3k4n6l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working. You just need an empty React Fragment to enclose the tags.

```jsx
{
  options.map((option, index) => (
    <>
      <Checkbox
        key={option.name}
        isChecked={option.checked}
        checkHandler={() => updateCheckStatus(index)}
        label={option.name}
        index={index}
      />
      {option.checked ? (
        <input
          type="text"
          id={`input_${option.name}`}
          name={`name_${option.name}`}
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  ));
}
```

and to your second question, you can simply use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to take out only selected options.

```jsx
const handlePrintResults = () => {
  // Filter only checked options
  const onlyChecked = options.filter((e) => e.checked);

  // Take out only the names of it
  const values = onlyChecked.map((e) => document.getElementById(`input_${e.name}`).value);

  console.log(values);
};

// Add an onClick listener for the button
<button onClick={handlePrintResults}>Print result</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It just works fine. You know any way to also `console.log` the value of the `<input>` if the checkbox is checked?

Comment: added the same in the answer.

Comment: Your answer just logs the name of the `checked` checkboxes but not the value of the ´<input>´ or am I wrong?

Comment: Check now.. You can fetch it using `getElementById()`